# Can there exist a Non real Hermitian matrix Which is Diagonizable over R

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We know any Hermitian matrix is Diagonizable over C always .
And If the entries are real then it is a symmetric matrix so it is Diagonizable over R as well as C

So here my Question is.. Does there exist any Hermitian matrix with at least one non real entry such that The matrix is Diagonizable over R

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hermitian matrix $A$ is diagonalizable over the reals, then there are real matrices $D$ (diagonal) and $S$ (invertible) such that $A = SDS^{-1}$. Hence $A$ is a product of real matrices. And $A$ is real.